# Binomial theorem, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k{n \choose k}a^kb^{n-k} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I need to compute this sum:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n
 k{n \choose k}a^kb^{n-k} $$

It looks like I need to use binomial theorem, but this term $k$ really makes it tricky. I could obviously rewrite it to start summation from $0$ and include $n$-th term. I tried to use combinatorics approach, but can't really figure out how to treat this term. Could you please give me a clue?

Comment: Well, to compute the sum $k\binom{n}{k}$, you pair the terms of $k$ with $n-k$. Perhaps this will work here as well

Comment: If this is coming from an expected value calculation in probability, then the more straightforward way to compute that expected value is to use linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are hints to evaluate the sum in two different ways:

- Derive $(a+b)^n$ with respect to $a$
- $\displaystyle k \binom{n}{k} = n \binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Comment: The second hint is nice and powerful (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as choosing a student council out of a class. Here, $n$ is the size of the class. Then $\binom{n}{k}$ counts how many ways there are to pick a size-$k$ student council. Multiplying by $k$ means you pick one member of the student council to be special, say, the class president. The factor of $a^kb^{n-k}$ means that for each of the $k$ student council members, you pick one thing out of $a$ options, and for each of the $n-k$ non-council members, you pick one thing out of $b$ options. We can think of this as assigning tasks to students. There are $a$ tasks that can be assigned only to council members, and $b$ tasks that can be assigned only to non-council members, with the caveat that many students can be assigned to the same task, and some tasks may be assigned to nobody.

We got this sum by first picking the student council, then picking the president and assigning tasks. What if you tried doing this in reverse order?